# How can you format times into AP style with PHP?

Tags: php, datetime-format

I need to format some times into AP style using PHP.

[AP style dictates](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/735/02/) that when a time is on the hour, ":00" should be omitted. And periods should be used in a.m./p.m.

E.g.: 1 p.m. and 3:30 a.m.

As far as I can tell, PHP doesn't provide a built-in way to do this. The only way I can think of to accomplish it is through a series of if statements, but that seems a bit klunky to me.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Short answer: no, PHP does not natively support AP style. You can do it in the way you describe. You encounter similar issues when formatting currency for instance. Since your question does not contain any code it's hard to give a definitive answer. It's border-line off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert to the string first, then str_replace to correct the format?

```
function apStyle($date){

  $date = strftime("%l:%M %P", strtotime($date));

  $date = str_replace(":00", "", $date);
  $date = str_replace("m", ".m.", $date);

  return $date;

}
```